# QueryDSL paginating results for older versions of SQL server (limit/offset)

Tags: sql-server, pagination, querydsl

How can I paginate the results of a query using QueryDSL in older versions of MS SQL Server?  For Oracle and SQL Server 2012+ I can do this:

```
query.offset(startIndex).limit(size);
```

However, this doesn't work in older versions of SQL server since offset isn't supported.  I know the SQL code that needs to be gerenated is something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      Orders
          WHERE     OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum < 20
ORDER BY RowNum
```

What's the best way to do this in QueryDSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querydsl provides three different SQLServer dialects

- `SQLServerTemplates` for SQL Server versions before 2005
- `SQLServerTemplates2005` for SQL Server 2005 and 2008
- `SQLServerTemplates2012` for SQL Server 2012

`SQLServerTemplates` doesn't support offset, but the other two do